# multiple entry labels in tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I am a beginning (emphasis) programmer, and I am creating a study GUI application. I want to create multiple Entry fields for terms, and definitions. To create one Entry box, the code ( I believe) would be:

```
term = StringVar()
term1 = Entry(root, textvariable = term)
term1.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

My goal is to be able to prompt the user asking how many terms they want. My question is what loop would I have to run to automatically create a column of entry fields, specific to the number the user entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have got the user input `x`, an integer.

```
for i in range(x):
    Entry(root, textvariable=StringVar()).grid(row=1, column=i+1)
```

But unfortunately you can not get the value of the entries then. So we can take two lists.

```
variables = []
entries = []
for i in range(x):
    va = StringVar()
    en = Entry(root, textvariable=va)
    en.grid(row=1, column=i+1)
    variables.append(va)
    entries.append(en)
```

In this case, you can access the entry and variable then using the lists.

Then you may want names, for example, `entry1, entry2, entry3`, within the loop. This relates dynamically variable creation which can not be accessed in Python. There is a hack way using `exec` or `__dict__`, but it is not recommended. Just use the list or dict.

Comment: Thanks, that works to spawn the entry boxes. However, when I have a button that prints the list (wether on the terminal or through a message box) all I get is something such as '<Tkinter.StringVar instance at 0x102532a28>' for each term in the list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use the `.get()` method of `StringVar` to achieve the values.@TylerJones